# Pandas SettingWithCopyError

Tags: pandas

I still do not quite understand the `SettingWithCopyError`, none of the following seem to work:

`df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year`

`df.loc[:,'year'] = df['date'].dt.year`

`df.loc[:,'year'] = df.loc[:,'date'].dt.year`

`pd.__version__` '0.25.3'

Thank you!

The complete code:

```
df = other_df[['id','date','price']]

def date_augment(df, col):
    field =  df[col]
    attr = ['Year', 'Month', 'Week', 'Day', 'Dayofweek', 'Dayofyear', 'Is_month_end', 'Is_month_start', 
        'Is_quarter_end', 'Is_quarter_start', 'Is_year_end', 'Is_year_start']
    for n in attr: df[n] = getattr(field.dt, n.lower())
    df['Elapsed'] = field.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9

date_augment(df, 'date')
```

Comment: I think obviously problem is in code above  `df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year`, solution is obviously `.copy`

Comment: @jezrael can you be more specific on how to use your solution?

Comment: Can you add your all code?

Comment: @jezrael `df['date'].dtype`
`dtype('<M8[ns]')` I have just got a column of dates

Comment: I not ask for dtype, but for your completely code

Comment: Change `df = other_df[['id','date','price']]` to `df = other_df[['id','date','price']].copy()`

Comment: @jezrael the complete code see updated